# $.alert ({}); not visible/not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have an ajax call to the controller where on success i perform some action.
So in the success function i do certain validations.
In on such if condition i am trying to throw an alert message like this,

```
 $.alert({
 title: 'No Survey Points',
 content: 'There are no activities for selected criteria',
 confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-info',
});
```

But when i use just a simple alert like this `alert("There are no activities for selected criteria");` it works.

Can someone tell me where i made a mistake?

Comment: please make sure that you have added `alert` plugin properly on your page.

Comment: The correct syntax for alert is `alert()` without the $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer following jquery sweet alert plugin

[Demo](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)

Initialize the plugin by referencing the necessary files:

```
<script src="dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/sweetalert.css">
```

Call the sweetAlert-function after the page has loaded

```
swal({
    title: "Error!",   
    text: "Here's my error message!",   
    type: "error",   
    confirmButtonText: "Cool" 
});
```

Hope this is help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sweet Alert instead of just alert its just amazing:

```
              swal({
                        html: true,
                        title: "Message",
                        text: 'Hello World',
                        type: "success",
                    }, function () {
                        // steps if success.
                    });
```

But do not forget to link jQuery for Sweet Alert Plugin!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality in JQuery like `$.alert`. For general alert, you can use

> `window.alert()` or simply `alert()`

function available in native javascript.
Or if you are using any Jquery library like sweetAlert , you should follow their API .